# implement a user_controller for devise with a model user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have some methods now under "profile" like user blocking, banning, moderation.
It feels these should belong under "user" and inside the user controller.

Is there a way to have a user_controller.rb when using devise with a user model?

Reason for this is to scope all user related methods under the user_controller instead of the profile_controller as it is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is no problem with that. You can simply create `users_controller.rb` and interact with User model like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # do any stuff you need here

  def block
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.block
  end 

  def ban
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.ban
  end 
end
```

For sure, you have to create routes for this controller:

```
resources :users, only: [] do
  member do
    get :ban
    get :block
  end
end
```

Like that.